# ZStack is not changing color

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've added `Color.orange` to my `ZStack` - but my view still has the default white/greyish background:

```
struct Settings: View {
    @State var minAge = UserSettings().minAge
    @State var maxAge = UserSettings().maxAge
    @State var chosenSeeking = UserSettings.Seeking.both

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.orange
            VStack {
                NavigationView {
                        Form {
                            Section {
                                Picker("Look for", selection: $chosenSeeking) {
                                    ForEach(UserSettings.Seeking.allCases) { i in
                                        Text(String(i.rawValue))
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            Section {
                                Text("Min age")
                                Slider(value: $minAge, in: 18...99, step: 1, label: {Text("Label")})
                                    Text(String(Int(minAge)))
                            }
                            Section {
                                Text("Max age")
                                Slider(value: $maxAge, in: 18...99, step: 1)
                                Text(String(Int(maxAge)))
                            }
                        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"))
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Best I could find was the `colorMultiply`:

```
NavigationView {
    ...
}.colorMultiply(.orange)
```

Comment: Probably not what I'm looking for - the orange layer goes over the `Form` elements too.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try editing your code below format?
I put ZStack under NavigationView, and in this case, the background color changes to orange.

```
NavigationView{
     ZStack{
         Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack{
               //some code
           }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `NavigationView` blocks the orange color. You would have to change the background of the `NavigationView` itself. With default views such as `NavigationView`, this is typically done by implementing a custom style of that view. In the case of `Button` that would be `ButtonStyle`. `NavigationView` does have `NavigationViewStyle`, however this is not yet publicly available. Our best hope might be the next major SwiftUI iteration, which will most likely be announced at WWDC this month.